# Proving a metric space is connected

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y )$ be metric spaces and $f : X → Y$ a surjective, continuous map. How can I show that $(Y, d_Y )$ is connected if $(X, d_X)$ is connected?

Comment: Remember that if $f$ is continuous, and $U \subset Y$ is open, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $Y = U \cup V$ with $U,V$ open and $U \cap V = \emptyset$. Then $f^{-1}(U) \cup f^{-1}(V) = X$ with $f^{-1}(U), f^{-1}(V)$ open and $f^{-1}(U) \cap f^{-1}(V) = \emptyset$. Thus, $f^{-1}(U) = X$ or $f^{-1}(V) = X$. If $f^{-1}(U) = X$, use the surjectivity of $f$ to deduce that $U = Y$. Similarly for the other case.